# How to get value of x and y here?

Tags: inequality

$x^2=16$
 $y =\sqrt{16}$

here I know that when we solve value of $x$ then we get two values $+4$ and $-4$

 But why we don't' get two values of $y$.
Can you please explain this. Thanks for help.

Comment: The principal square root function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a function that maps the set of _non-negative real numbers onto itself_. So it is only possible to take square roots of positive numbers. To take a square root of a negative number, you first have to go to complex domain, where you're left with an imaginary part and a real part, of which you can then take a square root of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an inequality but a system of equations, there are two numbers that squared will give 16, -4 and 4. By definition the square root function gives only one value ( by definition ), that is why $y=4$.

PS : repeating **by definition** is on purpose.

Comment: So according to you square root function can't be negative number ....that's why we y =4 not -4 ?

Comment: @Androiddeveloper : yes, **by definition** of square root function.